# Create WCF service with Integrated Windows Security on IIS7

Tags: windows, wcf, security, iis-7, integrated

I'm trying to create a WCF service that uses Integrated Windows Security and will be hosted on IIS7. 
This service is going to be used inside a domain and will be consumed by a java client.
My questions are:

- What bindings should I use ?
- How do I set up Integrated Windows Security on IIS7? (not the same as IIS6)
- How do I get the credentials inside the service (C#), that is, how to read the user name.?

Thanks,

Thomas